# Refactoring Ruby recharge REST API wrapper by using class variables

Tags: object-oriented, ruby, ruby-on-rails, api

I am trying to create an API wrapper for recharge (A Shopify subscription service), I am using the HTTParty gem

```
module RechargeAPI
  require 'httparty'
  BASE_URI = 'https://api.rechargeapps.com'
  API_TOKEN = 'my_token'

  class Client
    include HTTParty
    base_uri BASE_URI
    headers 'X-Recharge-Access-Token': API_TOKEN
  end

  class Customer < Client
    def self.search(params)
      response = get('/customers', query: params)
      self.from_json(response.body)
    end

    def self.find(params)
      self.search(params).first
    end

    def self.all
      response = get('/customers')
      self.from_json(response.body)
    end

    def self.from_json(customers_json)
      customers = JSON.parse(customers_json).dig('customers')
      customers.map do|customer| OpenStruct.new(customer)
      end
    end

  end

end
```

`RechargeAPI::Customer.find(shopify_customer_id: 5363543224286) # returns <OpenStruct accepts_marketing=nil, analytics_data={"utm_params"=>[]}, billing_address1=....`

It works fine, However i feel i am not using the best practices for writing an api wrapper.
Ideally i would set my api token with something like `RechargeAPI.api_token = 'token'` rather than it being hardcoded or in an ENV file. But i dont know how then i would use `headers 'X-Recharge-Access-Token': API_TOKEN`

Also ideally `RechargeAPI::Customer.find(shopify_customer_id: 5363543224863)` would return a `RechargeAPI::Customer` object rather than an `OpenStruct`. I would love to be able to inherit from `Struct` but obviously i cannot as I am inheriting from my `RechargeAPI::Client` class.

Could anybody advise on how i could go about doing this, or any way to improve this code.
Thankyou!

Comment: Welcome to Code Review! The current question title is too general to be useful here. Please [edit] to the site standard, which is for the title to simply state **the task accomplished by the code**. Please see [How to get the best value out of Code Review: Asking Questions](//codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2436) for guidance on writing good question titles.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I mostly agree with Sidney. Depending how big the API is I would not split 1 (A class responsible for your HTTP requests to Shopify in general) and 2 (A class that calls your HTTP class to make the requests; it calls the right URLs and creates the domain objects).

Here is an example

```rb
module RechargeAPI
  require 'httparty'
  BASE_URI = 'https://api.rechargeapps.com'
  API_TOKEN = 'my_token'

  class Client
    include HTTParty
    base_uri BASE_URI
    headers 'X-Recharge-Access-Token': API_TOKEN

    def self.search_customers(params)
      JSON.parse(get('/customers', query: params))
    end

    def self.customers
      JSON.parse(get('/customers'))
    end
  end
end
```

A good example how to implement an API wrapper is e.g. https://github.com/octokit/octokit.rb or https://github.com/Shopify/buildkit.

Then you can use your API wrapper to build your PORO / model classes like this

```rb
class Customer < Struct.new(:id, :name)
  cattr_accessor :client
    RechargeAPI::Client.new
  end

  def self.all
    client.customers.map do |params|
      new(params[:id], params[:name])
    end
  end

  def self.search(params)
    client.search(params).map do |params|
      new(params[:id], params[:name])
    end
  end

  def self.find(params)
    search(params).first
  end
end
```

Please note that I use a [class attribute accessor (cattr_accessor)](https://apidock.com/rails/Class/cattr_reader) to instantiate the client on the `Customer` class which is implement in ActiveSupport / Rails. This has the advantage that you don't need to inherit from your API class anymore and you can now use dependency injection to replace the client. For instance, in testing you can now use a dummy client instead of doing real HTTP calls.

```
class DummyClient
  self.customers
    { id: 1, name: 'name' }
  end
end

def test_customer_all_returns_customers
  Customer.client = DummyClient.new

  assert_equal 1, Customer.all.count
  customer = Customer.first
  assert_equal 1, customer.id
  assert_equal 'name', customer.name
end
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you should have three classes:

1. A class responsible for your HTTP requests to Shopify in general.
2. A class that calls your HTTP class to make the requests; it calls the right URLs and creates the domain objects.
3. The Customer class, which should be more independent, should not depend on the above classes; in DDD terms, it's a domain object.

In this approach, you will be using composition over inheritance.

Comment: I like that. A Customer is not really an HTTP Client but rather a resource and should just encapsulate the business/domain logic (and maybe persistence if needed).

Comment: What would i do then if i needed to access a nested resource, e.g. `customer_instance.products`, Lets say in this example i get products by going to the endpoint `/products?customer_id=foo`

Comment: I would do it all with pure Ruby. The product would be a new model called `Product`, then `Customer#products` points to an `Array` of `Product`s. You can have a factory that, from the JSON, creates the `Customer` and its list of products.

Comment: There maybe be some gem that helps you achieve or simplify what I've said. I didn't mention any gem because I don't know any, and they may not be necessary depending on your use case. It depends on how much you are used to using the gem and the complexity.